# How make triangle div with css

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs

How can i achieve the effect in the below image using css
parent div with divs with triangle egde like in the picture below. if i can achieve this with JS am also open to any good idea

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav {
  background: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}
nav li:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 40px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #999;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
nav li a:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 40px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #eee;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Jewelry and watches</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">watches</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Jewelry</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Wrist watches</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Or you can even simplify it by using one psudo element and using the border property

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav {
  background: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  margin: 15px;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}
nav li:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: -1px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 30px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: transparent;
    height: 30px;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Jewelry and watches</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">watches</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Jewelry</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Wrist watches</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Mine is essentially the same thing but much less impressive: https://jsfiddle.net/yosgn0y3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

**HTML**

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vehicles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vans</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Camper Vans</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1989 VW Westfalia Vanagon</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.breadcrumb { 
    list-style: none; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    font: 18px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
.breadcrumb li { 
    float: left; 
}
.breadcrumb li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: 10px 0 10px 65px;
    background: brown;                   /* fallback color */
    background: hsla(34,85%,35%,1); 
    position: relative; 
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.breadcrumb li a:after { 
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;           /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid hsla(34,85%,35%,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 2; 
}
.breadcrumb li a:before { 
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;       
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    margin-left: 1px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 1; 
}
.breadcrumb li:first-child a {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,45%,1); }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,45%,1); }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,55%,1); }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,55%,1); }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,65%,1); }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,65%,1); }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) a       { background:        hsla(34,85%,75%,1); }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) a:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,75%,1); }
.breadcrumb li:last-child a {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: black;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
.breadcrumb li a:hover { background: hsla(34,85%,25%,1); }
.breadcrumb li a:hover:after { border-left-color: hsla(34,85%,25%,1) !important; }
```